# Ways to access SQL Server in .NET 3.5

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008

I need to access SQL Server 2008 in a C# project in .NET 3.5 (due SharePoint Server Object Model for SharePoint 2010). As Entity Framework 4.0 and above does not work in .NET 3.5, EF is basically out of picture as I don't want to use EF v1.

Is there a way other than System.Data.SqlClient that can be used to access SQL Server 2008?

Thanks.

Comment: Linq to SQL is available in 3.5

Comment: Why don't you use the traditional way? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many other ORMs and data mappers available:

Off the top of my head:

- [Nhibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx)
- [Subsonic](http://subsonicproject.com/)
- [Lightspeed](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/lightspeed)
- IronSpeed
- Linq2Sql

This closed question has heaps listed:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505/what-are-your-favorite-net-object-relational-mappers-orm